# ASP MVC 3 website error

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc

I have got a website on asp mvc and all of a sudden it has started giving me this error. 
I am not sure what does this exception means.

```
Attempt by method 'ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute()' to access method'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.BeginContext(System.String, Int32, Int32, Boolean)' failed.


Stack trace:

[MethodAccessException: Attempt by method 'ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute()' to access        method 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.BeginContext(System.String, Int32, Int32, Boolean)'     failed.]
   ASP._Page_Views_Home_Index_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Umbraco upgrade\ASIC MoneySmart v6.2.1   Stable (Final)\MoneySmart.Admin\Views\Home\Index.cshtml:2
  System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +280
  System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +104
  System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +143
  System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter       writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +157
  System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +378
  System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +33
  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter,    ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +727696
  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext      controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +265
  System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeAction(ControllerContext controllerContext, String   actionName) +727652
    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.ExecuteCore() +159
    System.Web.Mvc.ControllerBase.Execute(RequestContext requestContext) +334
    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__5() +62
    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__0() +15
    System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d() +52
    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +606
    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

Comment: If you are experiencing that problem in a Medium-Trust environment like Rackspace Cloudsites or GoDaddy try adjusting the application trust level. If you are using some external library that does not work in Medium-Trust environments try finding a version that supports medium-trust. E.g. Ninject IOC library used to have a problem in medium-trust and they had a medium-trust build for that scenarios.

Comment: I see umbraco in the exception stack trace, so you should check this page:http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/medium-trust-with-umbraco-45plus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem could be caused by the Medium-Trust settings in the environment you are running your app. Make sure to adjust the settings accordingly in the web.config. Per the recommendations on their [site](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/medium-trust-with-umbraco-45plus) do the following:

1. Under system.web, create the following element `<trust level="Medium" originUrl=".*" />`
2. Under appSettings, set the key "umbracoUseMediumTrust" to "true"
3. Under the configSections, modify the section element that has name="clientDependency" to have an attribute requirePermission="false"

You should also update any external libraries that don't work in Medium-Trust to support medium-trust. For example Ninject IOC library has a separate library version for Medium-Trust environments.

In addition there have been reported issues of **MethodAccessException** when using a version of Umbraco installed using Nuget, so you should check this post for advices how to install Umbraco correctly using Nuget:

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Installation/install-umbraco-with-nuget

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the help.. Actually there was another problem in my project I was using the different versions of assemblies. Adding the following code in the web.config solved my problem

```
  <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers"
         publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
    <dependentAssembly>
     <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages"
         publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0"/>
    </dependentAssembly>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.methodaccessexception(v=vs.110).aspx),

> The exception that is thrown when there is an invalid attempt to access a method, such as accessing a private method from partially trusted code.
>
> This exception is thrown in situations such as the following:
>
> - A private, protected, or internal method that would not be accessible from normal compiled code is accessed from partially trusted code by using reflection.
> - A security-critical method is accessed from transparent code.
> - The access level of a method in a class library has changed, and one or more assemblies that reference the library have not been recompiled.

Maybe try adjusting the [application's trust level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wyts434y(v=vs.100).aspx).